# Why SKlearn and WEKA results do not match?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, weka, random-forest

I have this [dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tS7BGQmRkbw3XREZGWET9XMJPfpxLIXW/view?usp=sharing), and I'm using SKlearn to generate a random forest model as follows:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RandomForest
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score, cross_val_predict
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('trainingSetExample.csv')
X_train = df.iloc[:, df.columns != 'label']
y_train = df.ix[:]['label']
clf = RandomForest() 
print np.mean(cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=10))
print 'precision', np.mean(cross_val_score(clf, X_train, y_train, cv=10, scoring='precision_macro'))
```

Accuracy and precision are both 0.99, but when I use WEKA random-forest, accuracy and precision are both 0.95. It looks like the default values of the parameters for both is the same, in addition, I tried WEKA with 10000 iterations instead of 100 and it didn't improve.

Why are the results that much different?

Comment: You should also post the complete code of Weka as well as data used in both.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the error, the label was included in features by mistake, so SKlearn always reported a high accuracy (close to 1), but WEKA was smart enough to remove that feature and report the actual accuracy. After removing that column, they both match.